# Custom alert box for different screen size using javascript and for different browsers of android

Tags: javascript, android, css, cross-browser, hybrid

I have used custom alert box to hide the header javascript says and that worked but now as I want to use it on different browsers and android devoce browsers , the alert box seems misplaced on page and also becomes big for certain android devices. How can I use css or sone otherjs script to adjust my alert box so that it can come in center and be used for different  browsers. Below is frm where I took code for alert box.
http://www.developphp.com/view.php?tid=1384

please suggest some changes from this code reference .

Comment: http://fabien-d.github.io/alertify.js/ alertify.js has some great options

Answer (score 0):

The best (or at least easiest) way is to use an existing javascript library that is already designed to maximise cross-browser support. For instance, take a look at jQuery's dialog functionality: http://jqueryui.com/dialog/

Answer (score 0):

If you are targetting mobile devices then I would suggest you to use mobile JavaScript frameworks. For instance, if you use jQuery Mobile then you wouldn't have to worry about this problem because it follows responsive design : [Read more here](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.2/)

It also has the popup component which might be what you're looking for:
[JQM popup](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.2/popup/)